# Problema ao montar grafico com ggplot2 R

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, reshape

Estou tentando montar um gráfico em R para exibir os valores máximos e mínimos de algumas variáveis além de uma linha para marcar o 0 do y, entretanto os pontos do gráfico saem completamente fora de ordem.

Estou utilizando a seguinte tabela:

```
cultivar <- c("IB0094", "IB0094", "IB0094", "IB0094", "IB0094", "IB0094", "IB0095", "IB0095", "IB0095", "IB0095", "IB0095", "IB0095")

parametro <- c("CSDL", "SDPDV", "PODUR", "THRSH", "SDPRO", "SDLIP", "CSDL", "SDPDV", "PODUR", "THRSH", "SDPRO", "SDLIP")

ValorMaximo <- c(299.96338, 299.96338, 199.76807, 68.15185, 46.39892, 138.90381, 299.96338, 299.96338, 124.18213, 9.63135, 45.08056, 299.96338)

ValorMinimo <- c(-98.95166, -98.7583, -79.51904, -8.8462, -48.96826, -98.95166, -98.95166, -98.95166, -98.95166, -5.17236, -77.87549, -98.95166)

res <- data.frame(cultivar, parametro, ValorMaximo, ValorMinimo)
```

E o seguinte código:

```
tbl = melt(res, id.vars =c("cultivar","parametro")  , value.name="valor", variable.name="Variable", na.rm=TRUE)

tbl$cultivar = as.factor(tbl$cultivar)
tbl$parametro = as.factor(tbl$parametro)

ggplot(tbl, aes(x=parametro, y=sort(valor, decreasing = T), fill=Variable, group = Variable)) + geom_point(stat="identity", aes(colour = Variable, shape = Variable), size = 5) +
    geom_hline(yintercept = 0) + ggtitle("Valores de variacao para os CG's dos cultivares") +
    facet_grid(. ~ cultivar) + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1), panel.grid.minor.y = element_blank(), panel.grid.major.y = element_blank()) +
    labs(y = "Valor", x = "Coeficiente genetico")
```

Não consegui inserir o resultado final devido ao tamanho do arquivo.
Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Se entendi bem o teu problema, basta retirar o `sort` do argumento `y` da função `ggplot`:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape)

cultivar <- c("IB0094", "IB0094", "IB0094", "IB0094", "IB0094", "IB0094", "IB0095",     "IB0095", "IB0095", "IB0095", "IB0095", "IB0095")

parametro <- c("CSDL", "SDPDV", "PODUR", "THRSH", "SDPRO", "SDLIP", "CSDL",     "SDPDV", "PODUR", "THRSH", "SDPRO", "SDLIP")

ValorMaximo <- c(299.96338, 299.96338, 199.76807, 68.15185, 46.39892, 138.90381, 299    .96338, 299.96338, 124.18213, 9.63135, 45.08056, 299.96338)

ValorMinimo <- c(-98.95166, -98.7583, -79.51904, -8.8462, -48.96826, -98.95166, -98.    95166, -98.95166, -98.95166, -5.17236, -77.87549, -98.95166)

res <- data.frame(cultivar, parametro, ValorMaximo, ValorMinimo)

tbl <- melt(res, id.vars=c("cultivar","parametro"), value.name="valor", variable.    name="Variable", na.rm=TRUE)

ggplot(tbl, aes(x=parametro, y=value, fill=variable, group = variable)) + geom_point(stat="identity", aes(colour = variable, shape = variable), size = 5) + geom_hline(yintercept = 0) + ggtitle("Valores de variacao para os CG's dos cultivares") + facet_grid(. ~ cultivar) + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1), panel.grid.minor.y = element_blank(), panel.grid.major.y = element_blank()) + labs(y = "Valor", x = "Coeficiente genetico")

> res
cultivar parametro ValorMaximo ValorMinimo
1    IB0094      CSDL   299.96338   -98.95166
2    IB0094     SDPDV   299.96338   -98.75830
3    IB0094     PODUR   199.76807   -79.51904
4    IB0094     THRSH    68.15185    -8.84620
5    IB0094     SDPRO    46.39892   -48.96826
6    IB0094     SDLIP   138.90381   -98.95166
7    IB0095      CSDL   299.96338   -98.95166
8    IB0095     SDPDV   299.96338   -98.95166
9    IB0095     PODUR   124.18213   -98.95166
10   IB0095     THRSH     9.63135    -5.17236
11   IB0095     SDPRO    45.08056   -77.87549
12   IB0095     SDLIP   299.96338   -98.95166
```

[image: Resultado do ggplot]

Comment: Consegui resolver, o problema não era apenas o sort, mas sim  que eu estava testando com um objeto do tipo data.table do pacote "data.table" e isso estava desordenando todo o gráfico...não sei o pq...